# Using Module Produces NoneType AttributeError

Tags: python

The code looks something like this:

```
import foo
import snoo

Class Blah:

# stuff

def Cleanup(self):
    if self.thing is not None:
        try:
            foo.helpCleanup()
        except snoo.specificException(ALREADY_CLEANED_UP):
            pass

    self.thing = None

def __del__(self):
    self.Cleanup()

# other stuff
```

The line reading snoo.specificException(ALREADY_CLEANED_UP):

is throwing an exception like: AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no 'specificException'"

Can someone explain how this works? I've used python a bit, but I'm not an expert on how it cleans things up. It looks to me like the module snoo has been unloaded already by the time the garbage collector is destroying this object. Is there a better way to handle this than to catch the AttributeError? I'm worried catching the AttributeError could mask real failures later, although we are using a linter that catches most if not all of these beforehand.

Comment: When does Cleanup get called?

Comment: It's called from __del__, when the program is exiting. If you run it in pdb, it happens after you exit pdb (which I find very confusing). I'll edit my question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not depend on any imported functions in a `__del__` callback, because they are going to get deleted first. You can either directly cache the Exception class (the base class of all exceptions) or just ignore the error. Errors while `__del__` will get ignored and just print an warning in the console.

Comment: I agree that this code isn't ideal; the reason I write this question is more to learn if there's a better way to handle this as well as learn why this is happening.